# Why will the following code also call the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-semantics, copy-elision, nrvo

Why is it that when the `g_Fun()` executes to the `return temp` it will call the copy constructor?

```
class CExample 
{
private:
 int a;

public:
 CExample(int b)
 { 
  a = b;
 }

 CExample(const CExample& C)
 {
  a = C.a;
  cout<<"copy"<<endl;
 }

     void Show ()
     {
         cout<<a<<endl;
     }
};

CExample g_Fun()
{
 CExample temp(0);
 return temp;
}

int main()
{
 g_Fun();
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Because you return by value, but note that calling the copy constructor is not required, because of [**RVO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).

Depending on the optimization level, the copy-ctor might or might not be called - don't rely on either.

Comment: That, and the expression `g_Fun()` still has a return value, even though the statement doesn't use it at all.

Comment: @ratzip all the more reason - that's copy initialization. Same rule applies (copy c-ctor can be called, but not required to)

Comment: In C++11 g_Fun() is guaranteed not to copy but to move instead.

Answer (score 0):

A copy constructor may called whenever we return an object (not its reference) because its copy needed to be created which is done by default copy constructor.

```
CExample g_Fun()
{
 return CExample(0);    //to avoid the copy constructor call
 }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: ya agree with you completely. from last few days the stack overflow changes my mind about copy constructor. the book is http://www.informit.com/store/c-plus-plus-without-fear-a-beginners-guide-that-makes-9780132673266

Comment: It's still not correct. The copy constructor can be called, it doesn't have to.

Comment: but in this case he is creating the object then returning it.

Comment: yes, and? Read up on RVO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization